# Algunos atributos en phpMyAdmin no aceptan el tamaño de valores especificado al definir un atributo

Tags: phpmyadmin

Quisiera saber el porque en phpMyAdmin al definir los atributos de una tabla al especificar que sea tipo int(16) y luego entrar records a la tabla no deja en este atributo guardar 16 numeros. Como se podria resolver? Gracias, les agradeceria mucho si me contestan pronto.

Answer (score 0):

El valor máximo viene determinado por el tipo, un `int` sin signo no puede ser mayor de 4294967295.
Necesitarías usar `BIGINT`.

Puedes ver más info [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: oh ok muchas gracias.